# using the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (u)|}{u^{1+\alpha}}du<\infty$ to show the following inequallity

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This is not the complete question, just the part I didn't succed so this given might be unneccesary.

Let $f \in L_{p c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}) \cap L_{p c}^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and also for $A>0$ and $\alpha>0$
$$
|\widehat{f}(s)| \leq \frac{A}{1+|s|^{1+\alpha}}
$$
and let :$$
f(x+h)-f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \widehat{f}(s) e^{i s x}\left(e^{i s h}-1\right) d s
$$

show that :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (u)|}{u^{1+\alpha}}du<\infty$$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (h s / 2)|}{|h|^{\alpha}\left(1+s^{1+\alpha}\right)} d s \leq 2^{-\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin (u)|}{u^{1+\alpha}}du
$$

I already succeded to show that the integral converge but I dont know how to show this inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the  substitution $u=\frac {|h|s} 2$ after using the fact that $1+s^{1+\alpha} \geq s^{1+\alpha}$.